# NSubstitute Received with CONCRETE Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#

I have API:

```
 public async Task<Merchant> GetByExternalId(string externalId)
    {
        return await this.repository.GetBy(merchant => merchant.ExternalId == externalId);
    }
```

And I want to test it with:

```
Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>> expression = merchant => merchant.ExternalId == externalId;
```

But this:

```
  repository.Received(1).GetBy(expression);
```

doesn't work.

But this work:

```
repository.Received(1).GetBy(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>>>());
```

And how I can test Received to CONCRETE expression?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few options here.

First, we can skip the problem and test the query separately from the repository call. For example, the class being tested could expose a `ExternalIdQuery(string id)` and we make sure it matches a `Merchant` if and only if the `ExternalId` matches. Then check the repository received any call to `GetBy`. This doesn't test the complete process (doesn't guarantee we've used the correct query), but it could be sufficient, especially if we have higher levels tests. (In fact I'd be tempted to use a test against an in-memory repo or something here instead. The test as it is written is not giving us much assurance the system is working as expected).

If we want to stick to the current approach though, we can either inspect that the expression tree is correct (yuck), or check the expression passed to the function works as we expect (slightly less yuck?).

```
    [Test]
    public void TestLookup ()
    {
        var repo = Substitute.For<IRepo> ();
        var sut = new Sut (repo);
        sut.GetByExtId ("123");

        repo.Received (1).GetBy (Arg.Is<Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>>> (x => ComparesMerchantId (x)));
    }

    bool ComparesMerchantId (Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>> x)
    {
        // Option 1: inspect expression tree and make sure it matches what you want.

        // Option 2: run the expression and check it behaves as you expect.
        var f = x.Compile ();
        return f (new Merchant { ExternalId = "123" }) && !f (new Merchant { ExternalId = "999" });
    }
```

Another way to do this is to capture the query used in the `GetBy` call and then use standard assertions to check it:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestLookup2()
    {
        var repo = Substitute.For<IRepo> ();
        var sut = new Sut (repo);
        Func<Merchant, bool> query = x => false;
        repo.GetBy (Arg.Do<Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>>> (x => query = x.Compile()));

        sut.GetByExtId ("123");

        Assert.IsTrue(query (new Merchant { ExternalId = "123" }));
        Assert.IsFalse(query (new Merchant { ExternalId = "123zxcv" }));
    }
```

Hope this helps.